# Parallel batteries - blown fuse detection

Tags: fuses

We have parallel 48V batteries connected with fuses as shown below:

[image]

How can we detect a fuse being blown by a MCU connected with same common ground with a separate power supply?

Edit 1: Note that charger for the batteries is connected directly to the point after the fuse.

Comment: Current sensor ICs for each battery and switchable load, if the load isn't already.

Comment: We can't control the load unfortunately.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not bond the batteries and use a single fuse?

Comment: We would want to catch the situation where batteries of different SoC are connected leading to a surge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if a fuse blows but both batteries are at equal potential that there will be no voltage difference across the blown fuse. Monitoring current is no use if there is no load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8lq8Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Blown fuse detection.*

In this arrangement D1 and D2 prevent backfeed. If F1 blows R1 and R2 will pull the anode of D1 low and IN1 will go to 0 V. Similarly with V2,etc.

If you wish you could replace R2 & R4 with a 4.7 V Zener and this would give a constant logic voltage over a range of nominal 48 V. Replacing R2 and R4 with opto-isolator is another option which gives isolation between the batteries and the monitoring circuit while also allowing a wide range of sensing voltage.

---

Now that a battery charger requirement has been added to the question D1 and D2 have to be removed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW9tno.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Advanced blown fuse detection.*

How it works:

- R1 and R2 provide a 10:1 reference voltage from the battery. I've chosen the values to make the maths easy. You might choose higher values to reduce the current and heating. Note the reference voltage is 4.8 V (when the battery is 48 V).
- R3, R4 and R5 form a potential divider for the window comparator made by CMP1 and CMP2. Note the voltages are slightly above and below 4.8 V.
- When the fuse is OK *V<sub>CMP1+</sub> > V<sub>CMP1-</sub>* so the output is high. LED is off.
- Similarly *V<sub>CMP2+</sub> > V<sub>CMP1-</sub>* so it's output is also high.
- If F1 blows **and** there is an adequate voltage difference between V1 and LOAD then one of the comparators will switch low.
- Most comparators have open collector or open drain outputs so they can be wired in OR configuration as shown here. Either going low will switch on the LED.

You may need to latch the fault to ensure that the indication remains on even when *V<sub>1</sub> = V<sub>LOAD</sub>*.

R3 is adjustable to compensate for component tolerances. Chose standard E12 values for R1 to 5.

Comment: Any way to do this without diodes? This will make charging batteries not possible.

Comment: There is no mention of battery charging in your question. If this is a requirement then it needs to be added in along with details of the charger and whether or not the load will be connected during charging.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: @Transistor  M Rusten has aked if you wouldbeso kind to look at his related question. He thjinks your answer would sut his need with modification but does not have the skill to modify it. See here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/684551/3288