# Blown fuse detection parallel battery bank

Tags: batteries, pcb, circuit-design, circuit-protection, bms

I have 384 Nissan Leaf battery modules that I wish to design a blown fuse monitoring system for.

- Each module consists of 2 x LiIon cells in series with a separate fuse for each cell,
- The modules are arranged in banks of 6.

So in total I have 32 banks x 6 modules per bank x 2 cells per module = 384 cells and 384 fuses.

I wish to design a fuse monitor PCB that will monitor a bank of 6 modules containing 12 cells.

- Each PCB will have a per cell blown fuse detector.
- Each blown fuse detector will have an LED that  shows that the fuse is blown.
- Each  PCB will have a single blown/OK output and
- The outputs from all modules can be "OR" connected to a single circuit that will provide a blown/ok input to a Siemens PLC.

No individual per module outputs are required as the LED per fuse will show any blown fuse(s).

I do not have enough skills to design circuits.

Battery details.

Nissan leaf modules are arranged 6P2S ie 6 parallel arrangements of 2 series cells.
Each module measures 8.4v when fully charged.
Each cell is 4.2 V and I want to fuse each cell.
The center conections of each series pair of cells are connected in parallel across all 6 modules.
To sense upper and lower cell fuses I need a circuit for the negative terminal sensing and a circuit for the positive terminal sensing.
Each module of 6 pairs of cells is rated at 25A with 25A fuses.

I already found a circuit i would like to use [here](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/76724repz54b/stackexchange-2021-08-24-07_11_47/) from this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/582909/parallel-batteries-blown-fuse-detection?newreg=c32ef16eaf154e18864e94290b52a26b), but sadly i do not have the skills to modify it so i kindly have to ask for help.

(if anyone already have another circuit like voltage difference sensing on each of the fuses i would be glad to use that circuit too)

[image: Pro Painter]
[image: Testresults]

Comment: Please change this question so it is focused on a design, not asking for us to find something for you. Edit the question, thanks.

Comment: well the design is not perfect as it uses currentflow to determend fuse state. in my case it would be good enough to have voltage sensing, when under load and fuse pop there wil be a difference in voltage, same goes for charging. so its not about the circuit its about to find the best solution to the situation thanks

Comment: @Mrusten  Your question has been closed (not by me). Voltage Spike is a moderator - you need to listen to his advice. The question is a reasonable one BUT unlclear in intent. People here are able to give you as good an answer as you are liable to get any where IF you make the question clearer and (importantly) focus on what you are trying to achieve, and not on "what can I buy" - such questions are formally not allowed on this site. We don't make the rules.) The question can be reopened if the above is addressed.

Comment: Do you want 384 LEDs and monitoring points? This looks "not very hard" once the exact requirement is known.

Comment: @Voltage Spike is the question short enough now? what should i delete and still provide enough information??

Comment: @Russell McMahon yes i want to monitor 384 fuses, i want to make a circuitboard that wil monitor 6 fuses as in my paint drawing and just make 32 copies of that circuitboard

Comment: @Mrusten  I have edited and reopened your question. Please **very promptly** check the edit and ensure that it says what it should. It's not perfect (other stuff calls) but I think it reflects what you want.

Comment: I think that a very simple circuit will suffice. Hopefully others will look at this. If no answers in a few days nudge me for a possible answer.

Comment: @Russell McMahon thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to get @Transistor attention? im not allowed to post a comment on the post where he posted the circuit im asking to be modifyed, im sure he is able to modify it with ease if i could get hold of him

Comment: @Mrusten  I've placed a request re looking at your question on his answer.

Comment: **Important: Do you have electrical access to the rail between the cells?** <-- This makes a MAJOR difference to possible answers.

Comment: @Russell McMahon do you mean the center connection without a fuse? in that case yes the rail is accessible and also connected to the bms

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can tolerate a small current flow (say 1mA) across a blown fuse, I would simply place a sensitive bi-direction optocoupler and resistor in parallel with each fuse.  The optocoupler LED will "light" if there is a couple of volts differential across the fuse, which will only be the case if there is circuit load (or charging) and the fuse is blown.

The outputs of the optocouplers are easy to integrate with whatever PLC (or other monitoring system) you choose to use.

You could even place a normal LED in parallel with the optocoupler LED, and then parallel all the optocoupler outputs (select a coupler with open-drain logic output) for connection to your overall monitoring system.  This would give you a single "fuse blown" indication monitored by your logic, with the individual visible LEDs allowing you to locate the specific fault site.

*(The general idea of a LED + resistor across a fuse is commonly used in automotive fuse banks to indicate blown fuses, and as long as you can tolerate the leakage current works well.)*

Comment: a led need to high voltage difference to light up
voltage ranging from 8,2v to 7,25v in my case my goal is to use 60% of the avalible energy in the battery so i wil probably try to use the batteries between 8,1v and 7,5v that means cellvoltages between 4,05v and 3,75v thats only 0,3v voltage difference between fully discharged and fully charged.
i also do not think there is enough currentflow for the led to light as there is 6 high capacity batteries in paralell and im having low loads
so i think a circuit is needed to detect the fuse state is needed, i wil add module test results